# Binding нескольких коллекций как одной

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Есть коллекция (ObservableCollection) A, каждый объект коллекции A имеет коллекцию B (ObservableCollection). Нужно сделать Binding для DataGrid ItemsSource всех коллекций B, каждая из которых в элементе коллекции A и нужно чтобы при удалении элемента из коллекции A из DataGrid удалялись все элементы коллекции B которая была в A. Пробовал выносить все B в новую коллекцию, но при удалении A ничего не удаляется из DataGrid. И хотелось бы чтобы при добавлении элемента A, DataGrid добавлял все A.B.

```
 this.B = new ObservableCollection<B>();
 this.A.ToList().ForEach(a => a.B.ToList().ForEach(b => this.B.Add(b)));

 <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding B}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
     <DataGrid.Columns>
         <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" IsReadOnly="True" Header="Data" Binding="{Binding Data}"/>
     </DataGrid.Columns>
 </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Выложите код который сделали, его нужно всего немного доработать и все будет работать

Comment: Выставляйте в VM вычисляемое свойство `IEnumerable<B> Bs => As.SelectMany(a => a.Bs);` и привязывайтесь к нему. Главное — при добавлении/удалении элементов в `As` вызвать `NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(Bs))`, чтобы View перечитала это свойство

Comment: @АндрейNOP NotifyPropertyChanged не обновляет DataGrid

Comment: Обновляет, если сделаете так как я написал

Comment: @АндрейNOP "вычисляемое свойство" понял) работает) спасибо)